# Using "ContactsQuery" for searching particular contact in Google contact using Google API Ver 2

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api

Currently i am searching particular as below:

```
 Feed<Contact> f = contactsRequest.GetContacts();
    foreach (Contact e in f.Entries)
    {
     if (e.Title == "MyContact")
     {
    MesageBox.Show("Contact already exist");

     }
    }
```

This will work fine if no of contacts are less.But above code will become slow for large no of contacts.

I read about "ContactsQuery".How can i use it for above scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

**There is no support for full-text queries or locating a contact by email address**

If you want to find a particular contact, you have to retrieve all contacts then search for the contact yourself, there's no other way at the moment.
ContactsQuery allow you to filter by:

```
NumberToRetrieve
StartIndex
StartDate
ShowDeleted
OrderBy
last-modifieddate
SortOrder
Group
```

and other parameters defined in:
[Contact Data API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/reference.html#Parameters)
[Google Data API refence](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/reference.html#Queries)
[Google.GData.Contacts namespace](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/docs/index.html)